# Projection matrices in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is subspace of $3D$ space which is made out of vectors that satisfy: $2x_1 - x_2 - x_3 = 0$, and we are tasked to make a $3\times 2$ matrix $A$, that has $V$ as a column space, can we take any of the $3$ vectors?

For example if take $x_1 = (2,5,3), x_2 = (3,2,1), x_3 = (1,8,5),$ can we take that matrix $A$ can be $(x_1,x_2)$ or $(x_2,x_3)$ or $(x_1,x_3)$, or it matters which of the $3$ vectors we take to be in our matrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. You seem to be confusing the vectors and the scalars. Here, **the $x_i$s are not vectors**. They are the coordinates (in some given basis of your 3D-space) of any vector $x$, and $V$ is the plane defined by the equation:
$$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in V\iff2x_1-x_2-x_3=0.$$

None of your three vectors $(2,5,3),(3,2,1),(1,8,5)$ belongs to $V$. The two columns of your matrix $A$ must be a basis of the plane $V$, i.e. two linearly independent vectors chosen in $V$. For instance
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\2&-1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: can you please give explanation on how you got the matrix A?

Comment: The 3D space if defined by 2x1-x2-x3 = 0, not the subspace V, no?

Comment: And the x1,x2,x3 most certainly are vectors, the question says that the 3D space is made out of vectors that satisfy...

Comment: No, the 3D space is the space of *all* triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ where **the $x_i$s are numbers, not vectors.** The vectors are these triples. The subspace $V$ is the subset of those triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ which satisfy the equation $2x_1-x_2-x_3=0$, i.e. the triples of the form  $(s,t,2s-t)$, i.e. $s(1,0,2)+t(0,1,-1)$, whence the matrix $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your help